# Theorem of maximal interval of existance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand the above proof. What I don't understand is how does this prove that $\phi$ is well defined or that $\phi$ doesn't depend on $x$ because the domain of $\phi$ , $J$ does depend on $x$.

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Comment: @5xum, why did you delete your answer my friend. I found it very helpful.